# Novice Needs Help: Server Error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms, web

I am creating the contacts page of a website and want the div element to hide after a successful email has been sent. The Javascript function to hide a Div element:

```
function hideDiv(){
    document.getElementbyId(contact-area).visible="visible";
}
```

The code is called the by using "onclick" in the button element:

```
<asp:Button ID="submitbutton" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="hideDiv();" />
```

I get the following server error when i try and load the page: "Server Error Line 37:

```
<asp:Button ID="submitbutton" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="hideDiv();" />
```

Compile error message: ) expected."

I have looked online for this but cannot seem to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: do you have a variable declare contact-area or it is the name of the section ? in this case use 'contact-area' instead

Comment: that compile error message should have the line number in it. Can you post that piece of code?

Comment: what is contact-area should that be "contact-area" wrapped in quotes..?

Comment: the div i want to hide has Id="contact-area".

Comment: Scott, i did paste that line error, it is the code in quotes underneath (had to put it as code because asp: doesnt show up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `onClientclick`  insted of `onclick` will resolve your issue

so your code will be

```
<asp:Button ID="submitbutton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick  ="hideDiv();" />
```

Comment: This has got rid of server error, but function doesnt seem to work as the div "contact-area" isnt hiding when I click submit.

Answer (score 2):

This is misleading in webforms.  You don't want `onclick`, you want `onclientclick`.

```
<asp:Button ID="submitbutton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="hideDiv();" />
```

Comment: This seems to have got rid of the server error, the page is loading but the div still isnt hiding, but I will try and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net Button has two properties

1. `OnClick`

   It is used to hoop up server side method when postback occur.
2. `OnClientClick`

   It is used to call client side method.

So your button markup will look like: -

```
<asp:Button ID="submitbutton" runat="server" Text="Submit" onClientclick="hideDiv();" />
```

I guess you only want client side functionality, so you need to add one more line in your javascript.

```
function hideDiv(){
    document.getElementbyId(contact-area).visible="visible";
    // as you don't need server side postback
    // add this line
    return false;
}
```